# Checking why an Android device is not supported

Tags: android, google-play

I've struggling for a while to find an efficient way to check why certain devices are not supported by an application I'm developing.
From time to time I get a support call saying that a new update of the app is not supported.
I'm aware to the fact that sometimes I add some features/permissions to the manifest and I can't always support all devices.

The problem that in most support calls I don't have access to an actual device as reported.
What I did by now is sending several sample apps with various features/permission permutations in order to see which can be installed and which are not.

Any other ideas?
Is there any online service which I can send an APK to and it will make sure to run it on a specific device?
Tried, without success, but is there a way to imitate a specific device using the emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html), if you're using the <uses-feature> the play store should check the user's device for you, before allowing them to install / update.

Comment: I know that, just asking how to to know feature is failing the installation.

Comment: Looks like Google is using [getSystemAvailableFeatures ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getSystemAvailableFeatures()) to check. You should be able to use that to generate a message that the end user can report to you which lets you know what the missing features are. You can also use that to let you know not use certain optional features on that particular device.

On the other end, you'll need to document in your code what parts depends on what features. That will help you decide what's mandatory and what's optional.